# Ancestry of Bharath

Tags: mahabharata, kalidasa

In Mahabharat, Menaka on deputation from Indra to attract Vishwamitra unwittingly made themselves grand parents of a later brave Bharata King through Shakuntala..

So mythologically seen, the  Kuru race and so entire Bharat has no fixed matrilineal progeny before Menaka?

Who are brothers of Dushyanta and their offspring?

Comment: Didn’t understand the question. No matrilineal descent? The male lineage has their respective wives. Male lineage goes : Puru—-> Raudrashwa—> Richeyu—-> Matinara——> (Tamsu + ilini[wife])—-> (Surodha + Upadanvi [wife]) ——> 4 sons - Dushyanta, Sushmanta, Pravira, Anagha. Names in Mahabharata are 5 : Dushyanta, Sura, Bhima, Pravasu and Vasu

Comment: Thanks, that answers second part of my question in detail for the earthly royalty. . For the first part.. if we similarly trace upwards of  Menaka's lineage, she has no identifiable parentage and so there is no unbroken ancestry of Kuru  vamsa, except in the Indra Loka.

Comment: You want to know the lineage of Menakā? But as you know, Menakā is an apsarā, and she arose from kṣīrasāgara during samudramanthana. As per Nāṭyaśāstra, apsarās are creation of Brahmā, therefore you can call Brahmā as being the father of Menakā. Also, ancestry that is taken into account, is primarily patrilineal.

Comment: So Brahma is not a creator alone but is biological contributing progenitor of Indian lineage through Menaka...